# Sonarqube and checkstyle plugin. Not working custom rules (from template)

Tags: regex, sonarqube, checkstyle

I have installed checkstyle plugin in sonar 5.1 and I want to check if in my java code exists some string eg. BLOCKER in comments.

I created custom com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.regexp.RegexpSinglelineCheck rule and fill in values.

There is generated checkstyle.xml. But sonar not return any issues, but when I run this rules directly from checkstyle warrning is presented:

java -jar checkstyle-6.4.1-all.jar -c checkstyle.xml src\main\java
Starting audit...
test.java:5: warning: message
Audit done.

What is wrong when it is started from sonarqube ?

checkstyle.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.2//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_2.dtd"><!-- 
    Generated by Sonar -->
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter" />
    <module name="SuppressWarningsFilter" />
    <module name="RegexpSingleline">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
        <property name="ignoreCase" value="true" />
        <property name="format" value="BLOCKER" />
        <property name="maximum" value="0" />
        <property name="message" value="message" />
        <property name="minimum" value="1" />
    </module>
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="FileContentsHolder" />
        <module name="SuppressWarningsHolder" />
    </module>
</module>
```

test.java

```
 /**
 * Hello world!
 * BLOCKER 
 */

import java.util.*;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World! 2" );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have similar problem with it and also with RegexpSinglelineJavaCheck.

Comment: Facing same issue. Any Solution ??